# Diff stdin after piping it through a command

Tags: shell, pipe

I'd like something in the form of (fill in the blanks):

```
cmd1 | ____ cmd2 ____
```

That was equivalent to this, but without writing any files:

```
cmd1 > temp
cmd2 < temp | diff temp -
```

cmd1 isn't actually a command, it's a stdin stream from a text editor, so it cannot be run more than once, so this won't work:

```
diff <(cmd1) <(cmd1 | cmd2)
```

But that is essentially what I want.

I'm using macOS, but I'd prefer it linux compatible as well.

Comment: Do you need the diff output or you just want to compare?

Comment: The output from `cmd1` needs to be stored somewhere for it to be able to be processed by both `cmd2` and `diff`.

Comment: I need the diff output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split an input for different command and combine the result](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/183356)

Comment: See also: [tee + cat: use an output several times and then concatenate results](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/66853)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally when you do not want to write a file, you can replace it by a (named) pipe, but a pipe cannot be read by two processes simultaneously. In your case you can use `tee` to split your input and use a named pipe for one of its ends:

```
mkfifo p
cmd1 | tee p | cmd2 | diff p -
rm p
```

This, however, has one major drawback: the pipes have a limited buffer (64k on Linux), so when diff would read one of them excessively comparing to the other, the whole pipeline will be deadlocked. The problem can be circumvented using the `buffer` command for at least one pipe:

```
mkfifo p
cmd1 | tee p | cmd2 | buffer | diff p -
rm p
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554568/add-a-big-buffer-to-a-pipe-between-two-commands) for other buffering options.

Another solution for deadlocks is to use a variable to buffer the whole `cmd1` output in it (loading it to the memory):

```
cmd1 | ( b=$(cat); cmd2 <<<"$b" | diff <(echo "$b") - )
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought it might involve pipes. That said, because this is a stream from a text editor, it does need to be fully encapsulated in one command ideally. How might you extract the `cmd1 |` to be outside of the mkfifo? I don't know how to pipe direct stdin to the 2nd of a semi colon delimited chain of commands, in other words.

Comment: Also, it seems `buffer` is not standard (at least not on osx) so I probably can't use that. It's starting to feel like I should just use temporary emacs buffers for this instead, but then that begs the question on how I might send 2 emacs buffers at once to diff...

Comment: Because `mkfifo` does not read stdin, you may just write `mkfifo p; tee p ...` or create the fifo once, and not to bother with it here.As for the `buffer`, did you try other options under the link?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that, thanks. re: `buffer`, macOS lacks `pv`, `buffer` and `mbuffer` all.

Comment: @AaronJensen At least `pv` is available through HomeBrew.

Comment: The last suggestion worked perfectly for me. I added `set -o pipefail ;` before setting `b` so that if `cmd2` fails the whole thing would fail. Thank you!